# Deleting Users from multiple groups AD Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a .csv file with the group names and the SAM of the users I want to delete from the 10 groups.

How does this work? I am a PowerShell beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the user list as csv and use something like

```
$users = import-csv C:\csvpath\users.csv 
Foreach ($user in $users){
    Remove-adgroupmember -identity "groupname1" -members $user.username -Confirm:$false
    Remove-adgroupmember -identity "groupname2" -members $user.username -Confirm:$false
}
```

You could of course also get the groupnames from another csv to get a cleaner code

```
$users = import-csv C:\csvpath\users.csv 
$groups = import-csv C:\csvpath\groups.csv
Foreach ($user in $users){
    Foreach ($group in $groups) {
         Remove-adgroupmember -identity $group.name -members $user.username -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```